# close button on AVPlayerViewController is not working for first time

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I play a video from a URL with AVPlayerViewController, but when I play it for first time it doesn't dismiss and afetr that it works well
here is my function for play a video:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func playVideo(url: URL) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.player = player

        self.present(vc, animated: true) { vc.player?.play() }
    }
}
```

but when I run it for first time and press close button this warning appears to me, but after the first time it's doing well

`<AVPlayerViewController: 0x1048ade00> is trying to exit full screen, but is not in its view's window's view controller hierarchy. This results in undefined behavior.`

Comment: Are you have add childController player ctrl ?

self.addChildController(playerController);

Comment: where I should add it @MirzohidAkbarov

Comment: @MirzohidAkbarov I added it on my method but I got error

Comment: It it crucial to understand what `self` refers to in your snippet. The error usually indicates that you are presenting fullscreen controller in the view hierarchy that does not have access to "fullscreen". Basic scenario is when presenting within controller pushed inside navigation controller. It is the navigation controller that would need to present to full screen. You have very likely similar scenario. Presenting from wrong place.